# How can i create a snippet for $PointPriceLabel in php that round $PointPriceLabel to 2 decimals, with ceil round

Tags: php, wordpress, php7, wordpress-plugin, snippets

i was trying to do it this way

round(float $PointPriceLabel, int $precision = 0, int $mode = PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP): float

but it didnt worked :((

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Traduce tu pregunta, de lo contrario terminará [cerrada](/help/closed-questions).